# How to display multiple python interpreters in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, workspace

I am struggling finding a way for vscode to see my various Python interpreters, aside from the ones located in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

I am using a macbook and my issue is with my created Python venv, located at `/Users/<username>/pyenv/[.inienv, .mlnenv, etc.]`.

How can I set my workspace to look for python interpreters in other locations than the workspace itself?

There is no issue if I open vscode through the terminal by navigating to the folder containing the venv and executing `code .`.

VSCode docs say that the editor will look for a file named `.env` where you can specify environment variables, which I understand as I can set PYTHONPATH here. But, this is not working.

[Link to Microsoft VSCode documentations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file)

Comment: If you click on the interpreter in the bottom of vscode (or ctrl + shift + p, "Python: select interpreter"), then you can specify a full path to your interpreter.

Comment: create symlinks in your workspace for the virt envs

Comment: @Jeppe sorry I didn't list this as a thing I've tried, but sadly this does not work.

Comment: @rioV8 I want to avoid symlinks as I know that VSCode has options to solve this without, but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following setting in *settings.json*:

```json
    "python.venvPath": "/Users/<username>/pyenv",
```

Explanation of this setting:

> Path to folder with a list of Virtual Environments (e.g. ~/.pyenv, ~/Envs, ~/.virtualenvs).

Comment: there are 2 Python settings with `venv` and for both the description is vague, why does it not support `venv` virt envs, it does when the `venv` virt env is part of the workspace

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks so much @JialeDu, this works! I have accepted your answer :)

Comment: `a list of Virtual Environments` is a file with the location of the virt envs, what does `python.venvFolders` do different, can I designate multiple folders with virt envs

Comment: @rioV8  It seems that they are confused. Here are two github links hope to make it clearer. [link1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10004)   [link2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1479)

Comment: 3 years and they are still discussing over what to use and don't bother to make the doc strings clear what should be put there and make one deprecated, generate a message if used and delete it after a year, why make one setting specific to home directory virt envs, you can describe them with the general version, is `venvPath` a single path or a comma separated list of paths, why not an array of strings (like many other VSC settings) and the initial suggestion of Brett